# How to transform nested array to a flat array of nodes PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

I have a nested array with a structure as detailed below.

It is an org chart where an employ could have other employees related:

```
$tree_array = [
[
    'id' => 1,
    'employee' => 'John',
    'leader_id' => NULL,
    'team' => [
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'employee' => 'Maria',
            'leader_id' => 1,
            'team' => [],
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'employee' => 'Kevin',
            'leader_id' => 1,
            'team' => [
                [
                    'id' => 4,
                    'employee' => 'Alan',
                    'leader_id' => 3,
                    'team' => [],
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 5,
                    'employee' => 'Bret',
                    'leader_id' => 3,
                    'team' => [],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

];

Every node has an ID and a team, that could be an array of other nodes and so on.

I need to obtain each node in a flat array, like this structure:

```
$flat_array = array(
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'employee' => 'John',
    'leader_id' => NULL
),
array(
    'id' => 2,
    'employee' => 'Maria',
    'leader_id' => 1
),
array(
    'id' => 3,
    'employee' => 'Kevin',
    'leader_id' => 1
),
...
);
```

I've tried to implement a recursive function, but I get only the nodes of the last iteration.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a recursive function, like this:

```
function flatten($arr, $final=array()) {
    foreach($arr as $a) {
      $tmp = $a;
      unset($tmp['team']);
      $final[]=   $tmp;
      if ($a['team'] && count($a['team']) > 0) $final = flatten($a['team'], $final);
    }
    return $final;
}

$flat =flatten($tree_array);
```

Test it here: https://www.tehplayground.com/UHWCccFIkrS5v75Z

Comment: Thank you @Kinglish, your answer solved my problem.